# Inheriting view_form.js of module web in odoo

Tags: javascript, inheritance, odoo, odoo-8

im trying to inherit the module web. I dont have problems with the structure of the module but i need to change the behaviour of a function and i dont know how:

```
instance.web.form.CompletionFieldMixin = {
    init: function() {
        this.limit = 7;
        this.orderer = new instance.web.DropMisordered();
    },
    /**
     * Call this method to search using a string.
     */
    get_search_result: function(search_val) {
     ....
    },
```

I need to change the behaviour of the "get_search_result" from web/src/js/view_form.js, but i cant find a way to reach it by inheritance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: whats issue you face?

Comment: i dont know how to inherit the get_search_result function, cant find a way to reach it

Comment: have you achieved this, if please post the answer. am in same situation

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
openerp.yourModule = function(instance){
instance.web.form.CompletionFieldMixin.include({
  get_search_result: function(search_val) {
// Write your code here
}
});
};
```

Comment: It doesnt :/, i tried with extend too but doesnt seems to work

Comment: Did you add this js file using xml file. mean using `xpath`